# Sylius Emails all end with a Question Mark

Tags: sylius

I'm working with Sylius, and have been testing emails (order confirmation, shipment confirmation, etc). I'm noticing that the subjects on these emails are all coming through with a question mark '?' appended onto the end of the subject, but I'm having trouble figuring out where it's coming from.

I'll use order confirmation as my example for the purpose of this question. New order confirmation emails come through with the following subject:

> Order confirmation?

The body of the email comes through and contains unescaped HTML, even though the email is being sent as plaintext:

```
Your order no. 000000045 has been successfully placed.<br/><br/>Thank you for shopping at our store!
```

This is okay for now, as I will either remove the line breaks, or else figure out how to get these to send in HTML instead of plaintext. My issue, however, is the subject and it's trailing question mark '?'.

Here's the pertinent section of my messages.en.yml:

```
email:
    order_confirmation:
        name: Order confirmation
        content: Your order no. %number% has been successfully placed. <br/><br/>Thank you for shopping at our store!
```

And here's my orderConfirmation.html.twig:

```
{% block subject %}
    {{ 'sylius.email.order_confirmation.name'|trans }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% autoescape %}
        {{ 'sylius.email.order_confirmation.content'|trans({'%number%': order.number }) }}
    {% endautoescape %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the content of the e-mail in the profiler? Is the question mark also here?

Maybe it is a case of your email account settings?